# Bootstrap button reset

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Click the Default button to add active class but why is the reset button not resetting the button state?

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('#test').button('reset');
})
```

HTML

```
<p>
<button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">Default</button>
</p>
<p>
<button id="reset">
Reset
</button>
</p>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rdh579hc/1/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/

Comment: @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi `.button('reset')` is a [bootstrap method](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-methods), not related to the jQuery selector.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rdh579hc/2/

Comment: To me the description of the method (`Resets button state - swaps text to original text.`) sounds like it is only supposed to reset the text of the button, nothing more. But I could be interpreting it wrong.

Comment: But in your fiddle I see the button already has default text so what do you expect to happen when `reset` method is called?

Comment: I'm not sure what `reset` method is supposed to do regarding active state. Reading the DOC as provided in comment above, it should reset its state so i'm not sure why your code doesn't work as expected. Here a workaround using `$('#test.active').button('toggle')` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/rdh579hc/5/

Comment: If I'm not wrong `$.fn.button` will only reset the button from its loading state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that to reset your button :

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
  var button = $('#test');
  button.attr('aria-pressed', "false");
  button.removeClass('active');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpfb7xeu/

Comment: Checking bootstrap source code, you should btw trigger change event on button element or just use `toggle` button prototype meythod: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/10606a73bcbfc6c723d60e2a1069c921afff0d2a/js/button.js#L52